# destructuring tuple with let in ML

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, ml

In sml can I use a tuple in a `let` ?  If so what would the syntax be?
I can require this as concentric pattern matches, but it seems there should be a less boilerplate way.  In the `let` below, I'd like to bind `v1` and `v2` to the two values of the tuple returned from calling `interpExp`.  Then I'd like to call `interpExp` with one of those values to get two more values.

```ml
fun performOp (e1,op,e2,table) = 
    let val (v1,t1) = interpExp(e1,table)   (* interpExp returns 2-tuple, bind v1 and t2 to those two values *)
        and val (v2,t2) = interpExp(e1,t1)  (* use t1 which was bound on previous line *)
        and val v3 = (case op of
                           Plus => v1 + v2
                     | Minus => v1 - v2
                     | Times => v1 * v2
                     | Div => v1 / v2)
    in (v3,t2)
    end
```

On further trial and error, it seems the second and third `val` are unnecessary, and thereafter it seems the `v1` and `v2` are not in scope for the next clause.

```ml
fun performOp (e1,op,e2,table) = 
    let val (v1,t1) = interpExp(e1,table) 
        and (v2,t2) = interpExp(e1,t1)  (* oops  t1, not in scope *)
        and v3 = (case op of
                           Plus => v1 + v2
                     | Minus => v1 - v2
                     | Times => v1 * v2
                     | Div => v1 / v2)
    in (v3,t2)
    end
```

On further experimentation I've discovered yet another syntax, but I'm not sure what the difference is, i.e., using `val` rather than `and` in the `let`.

```ml
fun performOp (e1,op,e2,table) = 
    let val (v1,t1) = interpExp(e1,table) 
        val (v2,t2) = interpExp(e1,t1)  (* oops  t1, not in scope *)
        val v3 = (case op of
                           Plus => v1 + v2
                     | Minus => v1 - v2
                     | Times => v1 * v2
                     | Div => v1 / v2)
    in (v3,t2)
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the `and` keyword is used in SML for introducing multiple mutually recursive functions or datatypes. For example, we could define gratuitously inefficient parity checking as

```ml
fun isEven 0 = true
  | isEven 1 = false
  | isEven n = isOdd (n - 1)

and isOdd 0 = false
  | isOdd 0 = true
  | isOdd n = isEven (n - 1)
```

And an example with datatypes:

```ml
datatype 'a exposed = Exposed of 'a * 'a stream
and      'a stream  = Stream of unit -> 'a exposed
```

However, `and` is also supported (I presume for consistency's sake?) in some other contexts, where it merely has the effect of introducing all the bindings tied together simultaneously. For instance, in

```
val x = 7
and y = 8
```

both `x` and `y` are introduced at once. To now directly address your immediate examples:

1. The first one you present will encounter a syntax error because it ought to be `and` instead of `val and`
2. The second one you present introduces all of those bindings at the same time, and thus you cannot rely on `t1` in the second---it has not yet been introduced.
3. The final one is correct with respect to using `val`

However, all of these also suffer from syntax errors because `op` is also a reserved word (it's principally used for allowing infix functions to be treated as prefix functions, like in `val sum = foldr op+ 0`). If you change this, leaving you with something like

```
fun performOp (e1, binop, e2, table) = 
    let val (v1, t1) = interpExp (e1, table) 
        val (v2, t2) = interpExp (e1, t1)
        val v3 = (case binop of
                   Plus  => v1 + v2
                 | Minus => v1 - v2
                 | Times => v1 * v2
                 | Div   => v1 / v2)
    in (v3,t2)
    end
```

then it should work as intended. I should also note that `/` is used for division on `real`s, so if you intend to work with `int`s instead, it ought to be `div` (also infix).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That `op` is a reserved word was something I didn't expect;  that's pretty hard for a beginner to figure out.  And thanks for the comment about `/` vs `div`.